# Correct preposition “The final exam in/on a course of/by Dr. XYZ”

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which prepositions should I use in the following sentence:

> The final exam **in** (or) **on** a course **of** (or) **by** Dr.XYZ.

In Dictionary.com the preposition *of* is said to mean

> **[of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t)**
>   2. (used to indicate derivation, origin, or source):
>   *a man of good family*; *the plays of Shakespeare*; *a piece of cake*.

Whereas *by* denotes authorship, or the work of someone

> **[by](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/by?s=t)**:
>   11. through the agency, efficacy, work, participation, or authority of:
>   *The book was published by Random House.*

Comment: @Jolenealaska why would *from* be needed? The OP didn't miss "by" it was always included in the original question.

Comment: Twas a lame joke.

Comment: For what it's worth, the most natural words that come to me are *a final exam for a course with Dr. XYZ*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exam may be *on* or *over* a topic, but it occurs *in* a class.

The course taught by Dr X is neither the course *of* Dr X nor the course *by* Dr X but *Dr X's* course.